# #ifdef analog for LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, compiling

For example there is a simple tex-file with following text:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (0.4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to modifiy it so: if I `\include` it another TeX file it is compiled as a picture in a document, while if it is compiled alone (say:`pdflatex myfile.tex`) it results in a standalone pdf file as the unmodified file?

Comment: The `standalone` package (not class) in the main file should help.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/2703707 answer the question?

Comment: You won't be using `\include`, but `\input`: the former always adds a page break.

Comment: The `standalone` package is just what I needed! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example tex-file using `standalone` package (based on answer by egreg):

`master.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p!]
\begin{center}
\input{myfile}
\end{center}
\caption{That's it!}
\label{fig:standalone}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Where `myfile.tex` contains text from the initial question.